# Is it true that for 0.3 or 0.6 seconds of sliding a panel away using React / Redux, we'd already have to dispatch two actions to handle it?

Tags: reactjs, redux, css-transitions, reactcsstransitiongroup

If a React panel is somewhat computation heavy during the rendering, and we'd like to make it disappear when the main page is also rendering something, it would speed up the page update by sliding the panel to the left or right of the page and hide it.  (the page is constantly doing data visualization both in the panel and in the main page).

However, it'd be strange, if the panel all of a sudden becomes blank or becomes `width: 0` due to the state `isMainPageConstantlyUpdating` is `true` and the panel has the line:

```
    if (isMainPageConstantlyUpdating) return <div></div>;
```

In that case, do we really have to dispatch an action, to set the redux state of `isMainPageConstantlyUpdating`, and then slide the panel to the left, and then at the `transitionend` event, dispatch another action such as `isMainPageConstantlyUpdatingForFullWindow`, and if this is true, then do the `return <div></div>`? (because the panel is already out of sight).

It seems no matter how I handle it, it probably has to have this two actions dispatched.  Can it be handled in a simpler way, such as, can the content inside the panel be somehow made to not update, and the panel slided away?  This way, all it involves can be one state, which is `isMainPageConstantlyUpdating`, and we make it not update the panel, and slide it away and be done.  But this has to do with freezing the data, which is typically *not* how React / Redux works (the data constantly gets updated into the redux store normally and provided to a component).

It seems we may be able to use `useMemo` to memoize the props, or the final JSX, such as:

```
const jsx = useMemo(() => {  return someResults(); }, 
                    [isMainPageConstantlyUpdating || someTimeStamp]);
```

so when `isMainPageConstantlyUpdating` is false, the array element gets the timestamp, and will redo the computation, but when `isMainPageConstantlyUpdating` is true, then it will keep on being true and therefore not call the function to update the content, but this is also making it quite complicated.

Comment: There isn't enough here to help you.  Check out react suspense - it can elegantly handle layout changes & dynamically loading data at different times.  You can also create a loading component in your suspense that looks similar to your data like FB - here is a tailwind css example https://tailwindcss.com/docs/animation#pulse.  You can also use an useEffect hook that listens for you updating state & renders a loading component when loading.  You can also set a loading state that pauses/restarts the sidebar loading in a useEffectHook. There are a ton of ways to do this but we need more info.

Comment: My gut tells me "no you do not need to dispatch 2 events". I've done something similar with modals and `setTimeout` where an in-component state handles the sliding, and the Context handles loading/unloading the component (although they were much more simple than what I think you are describing). I agree with @Sean W though, and that there's not enough here to be super helpful.

Comment: I was thinking there needs to be 2 actions (and two states), because there is one for `isMainPageConstantlyUpdating`, so that some other components need to do their jobs, while the `isMainPageConstantlyUpdatingForFullWindow` is for other components to do the job appropriately... I could hack it by delaying 0.3 seconds or 0.6 seconds to just dispatch `isMainPageConstantlyUpdating`, but then some components can be doing some task 0.3 or 0.6 seconds late

Comment: @SeanW it seems maybe `lazy` and suspense` can do the job... but to use them to handle something that is just for 0.3 or 0.6 seconds difference, it seems quite an overkill... what I hope for may be if a component can say, `if (isMainPageConstantlyUpdating && !isMainPageConstantlyUpdatingForFullWindow) { freezeTheRendering() }` and that will do the job. But there seems no easy way to do `freezeTheRendering()`

Comment: I would let them load when they load independently of each other with nice placeholders that prevent the layout from shifting during and after load. That way if the first query gets hung up the other one doesn't suffer.  If you really wanted you could use the same state for both components but we'd need to see an example to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying and it seems one solution is that we don't have to manage this "micro state" of after 0.3 seconds.

We simply can use a local state, such as

```
const [isNotToRender, setIsNotToRender] = useState(false);
```

so that for any animation end, we have a listener for it, and then set `isNotToRender` to true, and when true, then don't return any complicated rendering, but simply `return <div></div>` if we want.

I know the offical Redux example docs basically dispatch almost everything.  It was almost only dispatching to get something ultimately done.  I think it was dispatching something, and then use `useEffect(fn, [someState])` to kick start some behaviors.  That might be one way, but sometimes my style is more like: doing things when it needs to be done, and only dispatch to alter something that is more related to the data or important states of the app.